# ReactJs load div after consuming an api / server socket

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hello I have a loading for data I get from my socket.io
And I wanted my green div to only appear after I get my value from my socket.io

I'm wondering if I can do this using my state loading,

or would I better create a component instead of a div?

I'm a little confused how to do this or what better way to do this if I can use my state loading, or export a component with my div.

In other words, it needs to appear according to the value I get from my socket.io (something like my current loading)

[image]

my app.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import io from 'socket.io-client';
import Loading from './components/Loading'

class App extends Component {

  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this.socket = null;
    this.state = {
      queue: [],
      loading: false
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // io() not io.connect()
    console.log(this.state.loading);
    this.setState({ loading: true })
    this.socket = io('http://localhost:9000');


    const player1 = {
      id: 1,
      name: "spt",
      mmr: 1000,
    }
    const player2 =  {
      id: 2,
      name: "teste",
      mmr: 1005,
    }

    console.log('entrou aq');
    this.socket.emit('addPlayer-Queue', player1);



    this.socket.on('queue', (queue) => {
      if (queue === 1) {
        console.log('entrou no if');
        this.setState({
          queue: queue,
          loading: false
        })
      }
    });



    this.socket.open();
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.socket.close();
  }
  render() {
    const { queue } = this.state;
    const { loading } = this.state
    return (
      <div className="container">

        <div className="result">
        </div>
        <div className="ctnFlex">
          <div className="playerOne">PlayerOne</div>
          <div className="queue">
            <Loading loading={loading} message='in queue.' />
          </div>
          <div className="playerTwo"></div>

        </div>

      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

my loading.js

```
import React from 'react' 

import Spinner from 'react-spinkit' 
import ReactLoading from 'react-loading';

const Loading = ({ loading, message }) => { 
    return loading ? ( 
            <div className='queue'> 
                <ReactLoading type={"spinningBubbles"} height={150} width={100}  color={"blue"} />
                <h2 className='message'> 
                    {message} 
                </h2> 
            </div> 
    ) : null 
} 

export default Loading
```

Comment: is `queue` an array or an int ?

Comment: queue will be an array or an object

Comment: Every logic is working I just don't know how / what better to do for my two player div to appear only after fetching player data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
render() {
 const { queue } = this.state;
 const { loading } = this.state;
 const visible = loading ? 'hidden' : 'visible';
 const invisible = loading ? 'visible' : 'hidden';
 return (
  <div className="container">

    <div className="result">
    </div>
    <div className="ctnFlex">
      <div className="playerOne">PlayerOne</div>
      <div className="queue" style={{ visibility: invisible }}>
        <Loading loading={loading} message='in queue.' />
      </div>
      <div className="playerTwo" style={{ visibility: visible }}></div>

    </div>

  </div>
)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using your loading state property. You want to do conditional rendering in your JSX according to loading's current value. With this method, you can make the loading queue render while the loading boolean is true, otherwise it will render player 2 instead.

Base render method in your app.js:

```
render() {
    const { queue } = this.state;
    const { loading } = this.state
    return (
      <div className="container">

        <div className="result">
        </div>
        <div className="ctnFlex">
          <div className="playerOne">PlayerOne</div>
          {
            loading ? (
                <div className="queue">
                    <Loading loading={loading} message='in queue.' />
                </div>
            )
            : (
                <div className="playerTwo">{DATA_FROM_CONNECTED_PLAYER}</div>
            )
          }


        </div>

      </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot bro, I just got a little problem as my div disappeared the loading div queue went to the right corner>
Can you help me

Comment: I had a possible thought to solve this, but I don't know if it would be an option, instead of doing it with my div, I would create another component outside of app.js containing my user data when loading it updated ( the same logic used in the current queue loading)